# Unable to build app for Mac OS X, getting error

Tags: macos, ant, applescript, dmg

Iam building the .dmg file using ant script, inturn it uses applescript will peovide below.

Below is the error iam getting.

```
installer.mac:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/damuammu/Desktop/spark-Mac/target/installer
    [mkdir] Created dir:
/Users/damuammu/Desktop/spark-Mac/target/MixTalx_app/.background
     [copy] Copying 1 file to
/Users/damuammu/Desktop/spark-Mac/target/MixTalx_app/.background
  [symlink] ln -s /Applications
/Users/damuammu/Desktop/spark-Mac/target/MixTalx_app/Applications
     [echo] Create tmp.dmg
     [exec] created: /Users/damuammu/Desktop/spark-Mac/target/tmp.dmg
     [echo] Attach tmp.dmg
     [exec] /dev/disk2                  Apple_partition_scheme
     [exec] /dev/disk2s1                Apple_partition_map
     [exec] /dev/disk2s2                Apple_HFS
        /Users/damuammu/Desktop/spark-Mac/target/tmp
     [exec] cp:
/Users/damuammu/Desktop/spark-Mac/build/installer/mac/RightDSStore: No
such file or directory
     [exec] Result: 1
     [exec] mac/dmg_spark.scpt: execution error: Finder got an error:
Can’t set item "Spark.app" of disk "MixTalx_2.6.3" to {140, 250}.
(-10006)

BUILD FAILED
/Users/damuammu/Desktop/spark-Mac/build/build.xml:775: exec returned: 1
```

Below is the applescript

```
on run {volumeName, artPath, theHeight, theWidth, x1, y1, x2, y2, iconSize}
    tell application "Finder"
        tell disk (volumeName as string)
            open

            delay 2

            set dsStore to "\"" & "/Volumes/" & volumeName & "/" & ".DS_STORE\""

            tell container window
                set current view to icon view
                set toolbar visible to false
                set statusbar visible to false
                set the bounds to {10, 10, 658, 482}
                set statusbar visible to false
            end tell

            set opts to the icon view options of container window
            set the arrangement of opts to not arranged
            set the icon size of opts to 128
            --iconSize
            set background picture of opts to file ".background:dmgBackground.png"

            -- Icon positions
            delay 2
            set position of item "Spark.app" to {140, 250}
            set position of item "Applications" to {395, 250}
            delay 2

            update without registering applications
        end tell


        delay 10
    end tell
end run
```

Please can anyone suggest on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs in your ant script before the AppleScript is run. The error is here:

```
     [exec] cp:
/Users/damuammu/Desktop/spark-Mac/build/installer/mac/RightDSStore: No
such file or directory
```

What the AppleScript does is make your mounted DMG volume look pretty. Since not everything gets put properly in the DMG, the Applescript later fails with:

```
     [exec] mac/dmg_spark.scpt: execution error: Finder got an error:
Can’t set item "Spark.app" of disk "MixTalx_2.6.3" to {140, 250}.
(-10006)
```

However, what you need to do is fix the ant script failing with the first error.